# Problem with code that returns string like wave, after every loop the next letter will be uppercase

Tags: python

Without whitespace inside the string the code is doing what it is supposed to. But with whitespace it thinks that it needs to uppercase the whitespace as well.

As far as I can understand my code is related to the indexes, it does not matter if there is whitespace or letter attached to the index, code will perform the task.

How can I remove whitespace and reattach it afterwards?

Or can I somehow make the loop ignore whitespace?

Not on the subject but if the string had no whitespace, is this a good/efficient solution for this kind of a task?

Thanks in advance!

WITHOUT WHITESPACE:

```
n = "camel"

def f(n):
    x = 0
    print ([n[:x] + n[x].upper() + n[x+1:] for x in range(len(n))])

f(n)
```

Print:

```
['Camel', 'cAmel', 'caMel', 'camEl', 'cameL']
```

WITH WHITESPACE:

```
n = "ca mel"

def f(n):
    x = 0
    print ([n[:x] + n[x].upper() + n[x+1:] for x in range(len(n))])

f(n)
```

Print:

```
['Ca mel', 'cA mel', 'ca mel', 'ca Mel', 'ca mEl', 'ca meL']
```

Comment: Add an `if` to your list comprehension to check if the character is a letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a condition to do the operation only if the character is not a space:

```
def f(n):
    x = 0
    print([n[:x] + n[x].upper() + n[x+1:] for x in range(len(n)) if n[x] != ' '])
```

Comment: Using `if n[x].strip()` instead will handle all whitespaces